# Not able to set cookie in browser with Deno Oak

Tags: cookies, deno, oak

I am trying to set up Authentication with Deno, Oak and JWT.

Objective:

1. Send cookie with jwt token in the response.
2. Set cookie in the browser
3. Use the cookie for subsequent requests.

Route: Cookie being set

```
export const getUsers = async ({ response, cookies }) => {
    const users = await userCollection.find().toArray();

    await cookies.set("token", "1234567890", {
        sameSite: "lax",
    });
    response.body = users;
};
```

handling the Cors issue

```
app.use(
    oakCors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: /^.+localhost:(3000|4200|8080)$/,
    })
);
```

[image: Cookie is being recieved but I am not able to see this cookie in APplication --> Cookies]

Response headers has the cookie but the same is not set in Application --> Cookies.

Please help me understand this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `ctx.cookies.set` is how you set a cookie in Oak, have in mind that by default it's `httpOnly`. Your browser might not show it in that case or **you're looking in the wrong place**.

From the screenshot we can see that Oak is setting the cookie correctly in the response headers:

```
token=1234567890; path=/; samesite=lax; httponly
```

To check that the cookie is set correctly, just add:

```
console.log(await ctx.cookies.get('token'));
```

And you'll see that in subsequent requests will log `1234567890` correctly.

---

Since you're mentioning CORS I suspect that you're looking the cookie to be present in the wrong domain, you should be looking for the cookie in:

- localhost:8000 (server setting the cookie)

And not in your front end `domain:port`

So, if you issue the request from: `http://localhost:3000` to `http://localhost:8000`, when you're in `:3000` there will be no cookie present in `Application > Cookies > http://localhost:3000`, but it'll be in `Application > Cookies > http://localhost:8000`

Comment: Hi..Aplogoies for delayed response. Can you please help me understand how to use the cookie in localhost:3000 , objective is to use the cookie - token to authenticate the subsequent API calls.

Comment: The browser will send the cookies automatically, If you're doing a fetch request to :8000 from :3000, you may want to add `{ credentials: 'include' }` option to [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included)